# I need to edit the css properties of a link when it's active (a:active) with jquery after they have been set by normal html css. How do I do that?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this link( ) that has certain css as seen below attached to it. When I press the link, I move the link at a different location on the page. I need to also change the css in the a:active brackets after the link moves. Basically, I would like top to be 0px. The animate function happens but the 2nd line of jquery has no effect. How do I accomplish that?

Html

```
<div class = "buttons">
<a class = "About" href="#"><span>About Me</span><img src="#" alt="About Me"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.buttons a:active{
top:1px; 
}
```

jquery

```
$("a.About").click(function(){
        $("a.About").animate({right:'380px', bottom:'110px'},"slow");
                $(".About:active").css("top", "-=1"); });
```

Comment: $(".About:active").css("top", "-1"); });

Comment: i think you have mistaken by putting "=" equal sign here simply put value with "px"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery doesn't support an `:active` selector.  You won't be able to modify the CSS pseudo-selector `:active` from jQuery.  The best bet for you is to add a class to your CSS that does this.  And then use jQuery to `.addClass()` that specific class name.

**Edit**

If you want to change how a hyperlink behaves when you move it from Section A to Section B you could do seomthing like this:

*CSS*

```
a.sectionA:active { background-color:yellow; }
a.sectionB:active { background-color:green; }
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="buttons">
    <a class="sectionA About" href="#"><span>About Me</span><img src="#" alt="About Me"></a>
</div>
```

Then whenever you want to move the anchor tag from one section to the next, you can do:

```
$("a").removeClass("sectionA").addClass("sectionB");
```

Comment: Yeah that's the conclusion I was heading towards..how do you make use of adding a class to change the top value?

Answer (score 0):

Probably this suits your requirement:

```
$("a.About").click(function(){
    $("a.About").animate({right:'380px', bottom:'110px'},"slow");
         $(this).css("top", "0px"); 
});
```

Comment: That messes up my earlier animation. It gets applied to a all the time not just when it is pressed.